# iOS: audio files used in app sound harsher than when played outside the app

Tags: ios, swift, audio, core-audio

The audio files for our iOS app sound much worse when played through the app than when played outside the app. The sounds seem harsher and more "ecohy".

Here's our code for playing audio. Are we somehow altering the playback or natural sound of the audio?

Two of the audio files we're using can be [found here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fuu5bqdxuop3r95/AAAUZPjme9n5B3lTq-b2m6Uda?dl=0):

```
private func createAudioPlayer(filename: String) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    // Define file URL
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: nil)
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    // Create player
    let audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    } catch {
        audioPlayer = nil
        printError("Error creating audio player for \(url): \(error)")
        logEvent("Audio Error", userData: nil)
    }

    // Print status
    print("Created audio player for \(filename)")

    // Return player
    return audioPlayer
}


func play(file: AudioFileEnum) {
    if let player = audioPlayers[file] {
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.pause()
        }
        player.currentTime = 0
        player.play()
    } else {
        printError("Error finding audio player for \(file)")
    }
}
```

Comment: How and where do you play the file outside the app?

Comment: @hotpaw2 like on a desktop, for instance. any suggestions?

Comment: Your desktop system likely uses a different audio volume, DAC, amplifier and speaker than your iPhone.

Comment: @hotpaw2 how do we adjust the audio player to reproduce the same sound on the mobile device?

Comment: That sounds like a question for a professional audio sound engineer.  It might require some very expensive audio equipment.  Try asking over at sound.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the volume on the audioPlayer object to something smaller, like 0.05f, and adjusting from there?